# How to get a new object after form submittig?

Tags: forms, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I'm trying flask nad there is a simple task to submit a form.
Page is showing a one picture and a form, if form was submitted correctly, picture should be changed, if not - be the same.
I can't understand the mechanism of how to show only one object on a page and get another after form submitting.
Tried to use iterator over the list of images is folder "static", but my implementation was not working correctly.
Please provide me a feedback how to do it in rigth way?

Now I have the simple view:

```
@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def start_view():
    picture = None
    form = InputForm(csrf_enabled=False)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        picture = form.picture.data
        form.picture.data = ""

    return render_template('04-2.html', form=form, picture=picture)

class InputForm(Form):
    picture = StringField('What is on a picture?', validators[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

And a simple template:

```
<body>
    <form method="POST">
    {{ form.picture.label }} {{ form.picture }}
    {{ form.submit() }}
    </form>
    {% if form.errors %}
        <span style="color: red">{{ form.error }}</span>
    {% endif %}
</body>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form doesnt contain any pictures. It has a `StringField` and a `SubmitField`. If you want to see any image you need to have an `<img>` tag in your HTML pointing to the image location in your server
your view should look like:

```
from Flask import session
# in order to use sessions you have to use a secret key for your app
app.secret_key = 'some secret key'
@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def start_view():
    img_list = ['filename1', 'filename2', 'filename3']

    # if this is not the first form submission
    if session.has_key('current'):
        # if we reach the end of the list show the first image again
        if int(session['current']) == len(img_list) - 1:
            session['current'] = 0
        # move to next image
        else:
            session['current'] = int(session['current']) + 1
    else:
        session['current'] = 0

    picture = 'first_image_filename' # this should be the img on load
    form = InputForm(csrf_enabled=False)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        picture = img_list[int(session['current'])] # the filename of the next image
        form.picture.data = ""

    return render_template('04-2.html', form=form, picture=picture)
```

so template should look like:

```
<body>
    <form method="POST">
        {{ form.picture.label }} {{ form.picture }}
        <img src="{{url_for('static', filename='img/' + picture)}}"
        {{ form.submit() }}
    </form>
{% if form.errors %}
    <span style="color: red">{{ form.error }}</span>
{% endif %}
</body>
```

Comment: thanks, but show image was not a problem, how to deal with case when I have more then 2 images?

Comment: If your set of images is finite which I assume it is since you don't specify any user image uploads why not make a list of these image filenames and then choose whatever image you would like from that list?

Comment: This is a question about, how to take one picture after aother picture and so on from a list after from submitting

Comment: If you are submitting the form only once then when you render the page after form submission, you can only select one picture to show. If you want to switch the image after each form submission, consider using a session to save the index position of the image list so after each form submission, the next image in the list will be shown

Comment: thanks! could you update your answer to use a session in my case please? I'll use it as example.